# NSLog no output in LLDB. Works in GDB

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, xcode4, console

Since recent update Xcode 4.3 now seems to default to LLDB debugger. I just found that my NSLog statements are not showing in the console. After searching the for answers, finding none, I switched back to GDB and it works fine.
I find others mention NSLog in LLDB so I don't' understand why it fails in my case. Should it not work the same? Is there a different method for LLDB?

Comment: Fine a bug report with Apple: bugreport.apple.com Apple seems to feel a low priority to provide ivar display in lldb.

Comment: I'm finding NSLog statements work when I have "Launch - automatically" set in the scheme in xcode, but get no output when I set launch to wait for app to launch. Xcode 4.3.1

Comment: I've created a bug report myself about this.

Comment: I am not sure now exactly when it works or when it doesn't. I used GDB for a time then switched back. Log statements are working as expected for me now so I don't know what to make of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Switching from LLDB back to GDB also worked for me.**

For those who are not familiar with xcode, to change the runtime debugger back to GDB:

1. Cmd ⌘ + Option ⌥ + R to bring up the pane
2. Change the Debugger to 'GDB'

This will have to do until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Noob question: what is option ⌥ on the keyboard?

Comment: Look for that symbol on the bottom left of the mac keyboard. It's next to the cmd key.

Comment: Not all keyboards have those symbols such as my new MacBook Pro

Comment: It's a standard mac key. If it doesn't have the ⌥ symbol I can guarantee there is an 'option' key -> http://images.apple.com/keyboard/images/gallery/wireless_1_20070813.jpg

Answer (score 1):

xcode 4.3.2 lldb does not show multi-byte strings print by NSLog when debugging with real device,  but works when debugging with simulator. I just switch back to gdb by selecting "edit scheme".