# reverse geocode function not executing?

Tags: ios, ios5, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to use reverse geocode but the function is not executing and not really sure why..

Here I attached my code. Thank you for your help

```
//-- reverse geocode, converting from point to address 
- (BNRMapPoint *)geocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)location title:(NSString *)title

{
    if(!geocoder)
    {
        geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    }

    __block BNRMapPoint * annotation;

    [self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler: 
     ^(NSArray * placeMarks, NSError * errors)
     {
         NSLog(@"in block code");
         if([placeMarks count] > 0)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@", [placeMarks objectAtIndex:0]);
             annotation = [[BNRMapPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:location.coordinate title:title
                                                    placeMark:[placeMarks objectAtIndex:0]];
             NSLog(@"%@", annotation.placeMark.name);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"failed!!");
         }

     }];

    return annotation;
}
```

it is not printing anything at console.. so I figured it's not entering the block code.
But I am really confused why it's not entering. Thank you again for your help

Comment: This is a longshot, but this may be to do with the LLDB `NSLog` bug. Try outputting something in the `viewDidLoad method`. If you get no output, take a look at this. [NSLog no output in LLDB. Works in GDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519941/nslog-no-output-in-lldb-works-in-gdb/9925360#9925360)

Comment: it prints fine in viewDidLoad....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember having a problem with `NSLog` in a block passed to `reverseGeocodeLocation`. The Geocoder executes on a separate thread, as will the block, I expect. (I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong about that). In my case, I *think* `UIAlertView worked even in the block code, so you might try that ...

I reviewed your code against an app I have that's working with `reverseGeocodeLocation` and I don't see a problem with your code. The only difference is that I do a check for `if (![geocoder isGeocoding])...` before I do the reverseGeocode. That's just to keep geoCoder calls from stacking up, which may not be possible in your app depending on how your code gets called.

Comment: I checked the property, geocoding and it returned true. I call my geocode function in (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
 didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
     fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

Answer (score 0):

Possibly self.geocoder = nil?

replace

```
if(!geocoder)
{
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
}
```

with

```
if(!self.geocoder)
{
    self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
}
```